# Can I use MySQL with Android or do I have to use SQLite?

Tags: android

When using a database for an Android application, is it possible to use a MySQL database, or do you have to use SQLite?

What I'm trying to do is make an app that allows users to see events on a map. These events are updated by admin staff from the office from a Java-based application that works with the MySQL database.

Comment: what i'm trying to do is make an app that allows users to see events on a map. these events are updated by admin staff from the office from a java based application that works with the mysql database

Answer (score 1):

SqLite is present on the phone with some good tutorials out there to get you started using it.

Check the online docs for more details, and I suggest taking a look at the notepad sample, it will get you up to speed in no time.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you have to use sqlite. MySQL needs a server which would mean you'd need a locally hosted mysql server on a phone which is going a bit overboard.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use sqlite for your android side database

Comment: would i be able to create a back end admin section that runs from a pc to udpate information?

Answer (score 0):

The best is to use content providers if you want to share information. Android provides built in interface for sqlite (android.database.sqlite) and so sqlite is easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to Sqlite is [Berkeley DB for Android](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/bdb-je-android-160932.pdf) (Berkeley DB - Java Edition)