# Using Android to connect to mysql database

Tags: android, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm going to attempt to write to an app that needs to access a remote database running on a server. I know you can use jdbc when writing java applications, but can this be done in android too? Or is there a better way. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to connect android to online database?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6039682/how-to-connect-android-to-online-database)

Comment: This has been asked a million times already. Just search for it. In short: Don't do it. Use a REST service.

Comment: possible duplicate of [android database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738925/android-database)

Comment: @finnw: That's another duplicate, although it doesn't really have useful answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend implementing services on the server that would behave differently based on input parameters (e.g. userId) rather than try to connect directly through devices. Also, for performance reasons, I'd recommend the response format of json over xml.